# How can I find the region of a CloudStorageAccount using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm writing a feature for our software in which users can enter a connection string for an Azure Storage account, to which we can output data.

When we receive a new connection string I want to check the primary region of the storage account. I'm using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package to get both a `CloudStorageAccount` object and a `CloudBlobClient` object but I can't find any method on either object or related objects which would get the Location data.

I can see the Azure Storage Rest API has a method which has this data [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460802.aspx#bk_endpoints), but that looks like it would mean setting up client credentials or similar, which isn't going to work for me here.

How can I get the location data with just a connection string?

Comment: I don't think you can... there are some classes in `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage` that will return the location for a known storage account but you obviously need to authenticate.

Comment: Are you using classic or ARM storage account?

Comment: Location is a property scoped for Azure Resource Manager, not the Storage Account. Additionally the namespace is flat `account.endpoint_type.core.windows.net` so that's never going to reveal it. You should request Location as user input in the same step with the connection string.